# jQuery and CoffeeScript: What's a more elegant way to check if value is sub-string of table cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
narrow_custs: ->
    input = $('.narrow_custs')[0].value
    $('.customers_go_here tr').each (index, ele) ->
        if ele.cells[0].innerHTML.indexOf(input) < 0 and ele.cells[1].innerHTML.indexOf(input) < 0
            $(ele).hide()
        else
            $(ele).show()
```

The 4th line of this function is ugly and I hate it.  But it works.  If anyone can demonstrate the more elegant way of doing this, as I'm sure such a way exists, that would be swell.

input is the value from a text box.

`$('.customers_go_here tr')` is a jQuery array of table rows.

I need to know if the input value is a substring of any of the values from the first or second td in each row.

Wurd.

Comment: So you're only looking in the first two cells of each row? Why?

Comment: Why not combine/concatenate the innerHTML of both cells, and look for the index of your input form this string?

Comment: @Bergi  This is narrowing the results as the user types (it's called on keyup).  They should be able to type the client number (cell 0) or the client name (cell 1) to find the row they want (a specific client).

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts: So it's not just "all cells", right?

Comment: No, it's not all cells, just cell 0 and cell 1

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the innerHTML of both cells, and then look up the index of your input from the string. It shouldn't make a difference, but makes it look a bit nicer at the conditional statement (at the expense of one extra line):

```
narrow_custs: ->
  input = $('.narrow_custs')[0].value
  $('.customers_go_here tr').each (index, ele) ->
    haystack = ele.cells[0].innerHTML + ' ' + ele.cells[1].innerHTML
    if haystack.indexOf(input) < 0
      $(ele).hide()
    else
      $(ele).show()
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but I was hoping therer was some killer jQuery method I don't know about to avoid the use of cells[0].innerHTML

Comment: Also, is there some reason to add the input = undefined line? What does that accomplish? This function gets called on keyup event, so it's always getting the newest value. Not being snarky, just genuinely curious.

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts My bad. It's a bug from the coffee script parser I have.

Comment: Notice that concatenation doesn't work well. If you had "terry" in the first and "mun" in the second cell, a search for "ymu" would find your row, which it shouldn't. At least put a space between them.

Comment: You could use .textContent instead of .innerHTML to avoid possible matching on any HTML markup inside your cells (ex: a link URL)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to do something like this:

```
narrow_custs: ->
  input = $('.narrow_custs').val()  # returns the first value
  all = $ '.customers_go_here tr'   # the full set
  show = all.filter (index, ele) -> # the matching ones
    "#{$(ele.cells[0]).html()} #{$(ele.cells[1]).html()}".match input
  hide = all.not show               # the rest
  do hide.hide  # hide the rest
  do show.show  # show the matching ones
```